# October CMS Event Logging

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

Is there a way in October CMS to set log severity levels? Currently the system event log is turned on and working, but I would only like to log error, critical and emergency severity levels. As of right now its logging anything and everything. Which is drastically filling up log files. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [October CMS docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/error-log#configuration):

October supports `single`, `daily`, `syslog` and `errorlog` logging modes. For example, if you wish to use daily log files instead of a single file, you should simply set the log value in your `config/app.php` configuration file:

```
'log' => 'daily'
```

I think what you want is to set it to errorlog like this

```
'log' => 'errorlog'
```

Comment: I read through those docs but specifically I was looking to limit the log severity levels on each of our instances. So for example on development and staging environments the Log Info severity should be logged but on Production it shouldn't as this could fill up quickly.